# Apache redirect to https:/www only partially working

Tags: apache-2.4

I am aware of the many people with basically the same question as this one. However, I am apparently unable to understand the answers and thousands of blog entries on the web that try to explain the situation for me.

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04 hosted by 1and1 with Apache 2.4.29.
The only purpose of this server is to host a wordpress. The wordpress is only and reachable, however I need to specify the www tag in front of my url which I want to avoid. Here is my current redirect situation:

```
#### Working:

$ curl -I https://www.mywebsite.org
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 May 2019 07:36:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Link: <https://www.mywebsite.org/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8



$ curl -I http://www.mywebsite.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 24 May 2019 07:37:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://www.mywebsite.org/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

$ curl -I www.mywebsite.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 24 May 2019 07:36:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Location: https://www.mywebsite.org/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

####### Not working:

$ curl -I mywebsite.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mywebsite.org

$ curl -I https://mywebsite.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mywebsite.org

$ curl -I http://mywebsite.org
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mywebsite.org
```

I tried various redirect commands but I think what stops me from finding a solution is the fact that I do not know where to put the redirect information:

- Inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` ? If so, in which of these files:
  `000-default.conf, default-ssl.conf, wordpress.conf`?
- Inside `/var/www/.htaccess`?
- Inside `/var/www/wordpress/.htacces`?
- Somewhere completely different?

I tried out a lot of things but due to my lack of skills this is mostly copy pasting and I ended up in a mess. Not smart at all and I am very ashamed but for what it's worth here is:

`000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost *:80>

<Directory /var/www/wordpress>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
  # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
  # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
  #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
</Directory>
```

`default-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =off   [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^mywebsite\.org$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          "https://www.mywebsite.org/$1" [R=301,L]

    # remaining htaccess mod_rewrite CODE for WordPress
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.org
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.org
    Redirect permanent / https://www.mywebsite.org/
</VirtualHost>
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#   ServerName www.mywebsite.org
#   ServerAlias mywebsite.org
#   Redirect permanent / https://www.mywebsite.org/
#</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName mywebsite.org
        ServerAlias www.mywebsite.org

        DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
        #   the ssl-cert package. See
        #   /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz for more info.
        #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
        #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.org_ssl_certificate.cer
        SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.org_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/_.mywebsite.org_private_key.key

        #   Server Certificate Chain:
        #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
        #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
        #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
        #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
        #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
        #   certificate for convinience.
        #SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt

        #   Certificate Authority (CA):
        #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
        #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
        #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
        #SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

        #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
        #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
        #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
        #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
        #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
        #        to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
        #        Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
        #SSLCARevocationPath /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/
        #SSLCARevocationFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

        #   Client Authentication (Type):
        #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
        #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
        #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
        #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
        #SSLVerifyClient require
        #SSLVerifyDepth  10

        #   SSL Engine Options:
        #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
        #   o FakeBasicAuth:
        #    Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
        #    the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
        #    user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
        #    Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
        #    file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
        #   o ExportCertData:
        #    This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
        #    SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
        #    server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
        #    authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
        #    into CGI scripts.
        #   o StdEnvVars:
        #    This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
        #    Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
        #    because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
        #    useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
        #    exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
        #   o OptRenegotiate:
        #    This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
        #    directives are used in per-directory context.
        #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/wordpress/>
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
        #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
        #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
        #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
        #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
        #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
        #    This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
        #    SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
        #    the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
        #    mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
        #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
        #    This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
        #    SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
        #    alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
        #    practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
        #    this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
        #    works correctly.
        #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
        #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
        #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
        #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
        #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
        #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
        # BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        #       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        #       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and `wordpress.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName 12.345.678.910
    ServerAlias 12.345.678.910

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is `/var/www/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I know this is a mess but is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mywebsite.org
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

You have a DNS problem: www.mywebsite.org has an associated address in the DNS, mywebsite.org does not. Therefore, a HTTP request to `http://mywebsite.org/` does not even reach your server, because that name cannot be resolved.

Comment: I am even more ashamed but happy that your post allowed me to solve the problem. I set up a redirect for mywebsite.org to www.mywebsite.org via the 1and1 admin interface and it works. Thank you so much!